# CKEditor: Multiple config.js files

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have 2 HTML pages using CKEditor.

In Page 1, I want to use the default `config.js` file.

In Page 2, I want to use a custom `config.js` file.

How would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `customConfig` option and specify path to your config file

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config.js'
});
```

More information - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/?mobile=/guide/dev_configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

Not being a programmer, I had to play with it a little bit.

In Page 2 (html file) just before the `</head>`tag, I added the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = "../customfolder/config.js";
    CKEDITOR.replace(content);
</script>
```

"content" is the name of the text area.

Thanks